# Apache LoadBalancer URL rewrite

Tags: apache-2.4, load-balancing, rewrite, java, httpd.conf

I have one URL   http://ip:port/Parameter (apache LoadBalancer), If I hit this URL, apache LB should rewrite URL as http://ip:port/application/Adaptor/Parameter.

**Parameter** this value will change always. How can achieve this by using Apache Load Balancer?

I have configured property files.

1. mod-jk.conf
2. workers.properties
3. uriworkermap.properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding following conditions in httpd.conf, issue closed. Thanks for your support.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://10.0.0.93:18180/TEST/HttpAdapter/$1 [NC]
  </IfModule>
```